# Sub-Query returned more than one value

Tags: sql, max

I inherited this SQL 7 Code that has run fine for years here. But at another location, in another country, they get this error: "Sub-Query returned more than one value".

```
SELECT
lc.LoadNum,
lc.ShipFromState,
lc.ShipToNum,
(SELECT ShippedStatus = CASE MAX(lc.Status) 
WHEN 'Shipped' THEN 'LOADED'
WHEN 'Picked' THEN 'PICK UP' 
WHEN 'Cancel' THEN 'PICK UP'
WHEN 'WtLoad' THEN 'PICK UP'
WHEN 'Released' THEN 'PICK UP'
WHEN 'Schedule' THEN 'PICK UP' 
WHEN 'Loaded' THEN 'PICK UP'
WHEN 'WtPick' THEN 'PICK UP'
WHEN 'Picking' THEN 'PICK UP'
END) AS ShippedStatus, 
tp.Description AS PlantDescription,
tp.Address,
tp.City,
tp.State, 
tp.ZipCode,
sv.Description AS ShipViaDescription
FROM
vwLoadContents lc (nolock) 
JOIN tblShipVia sv (nolock) ON lc.ShipVia = sv.Code
JOIN tblShipToCust sc (nolock) ON lc.ShipToNum = sc.ShipToNum
JOIN tblPlant tp (nolock) ON lc.ShipFromState = tp.Code
GROUP BY
lc.LoadNum,
lc.ShipFromState,
lc.ShipToNum, 
tp.Description,
tp.Address,
tp.City,
tp.State,
tp.ZipCode, 
sv.Description
```

How can the MAX(lc.Status) function be returning more than ONE value?
If I remove the entire "SELECT ShippedStatus = Case Max(lc.Status ...) as ShippedStatus"  Sub-Query then the error goes away!

I replaced the Sub-Query with this line of SQL code ...

MAX(Case lc.Status When 'Shipped' Then 'LOADED' else 'PICK UP' End) as ShippedStatus

The new line of SQL code "appears to" work at all locations (all databases) even though the MAX() function is now "outside the CASE" instead of "inside the CASE".

So, how does the original SQL script allow the MAX() function to return multiple values?

Thank You!

Comment: you are matching every instance where shipped status equals that MAX, unless you expect exactly one record that has such a shippingststus. fact is, that query should be structured very differently.

Comment: I do not understand "you are matching every instance where shipped status equals that MAX". I thought the MAX() function would return ONLY the Highest VALUE of "LC.STATUS" field from all records in each of the GROUPS. Are you saying that if there are two records with the same MAX(LC.STATUS) then BOTH records will be returned? This "SUB-QUERY SELECT" is only a "CASE Assignment" statement to the ShippedStatus variable  of the Highest Value in the group NOT a SUB-QUERY of rows from the view or tables. I tested your theoar qwiuthhh

Comment: I tested your theory with "SELECT ORDER_NUMBER, ( SELECT MY_STATUS = MAX(STATUS) ) AS MY_STATUS FROM tblORDER_LINE GROUP BY ORDER_NUMBER". Which I believe is analogous to my issue above and test your theory. But I only see *ONE RECORD* returned even when there are MULTIPLE records (Order Lines) with the exact same STATUS in the GROUP (Order Number). Therefore, I am not understanding your reply.

Comment: "you are matching every instance where shipped status equals that MAX" ... But "Shipped Status" is NOT a field name in any table. "Shipped Status" is the computed value that is returned by MAX(lc.Status) and there is no "FROM TABLE" in the sub-query. To me, the Sub-Query appears to be just an assignment statement.

Comment: from an ANSI SQL standpoint, your CASE statement with the MAX applied the way it is makes zero sense. not only that, the CASE statement as a whole makes no sense (you're doing a scalar subquery and a comparison in your SELECT statement of that scalar subquery? eesh). I hate just outright saying this is bad SQL, but it is definitely SQL that does not conform to any standards, and I don't know how to "fix" this without (a) you telling me what the expected results are, (b) what you are getting now, (c) example data in this table, and (d) completely rewriting it to conform with ANSI standards.

Comment: @Plant Thelda, You said, "COMPARISON in your SELECT Statement". There is no "WHERE Clause" in the Sub-Query so how can there be a "comparison"???  Doesn't MAX() return a SCALAR from the GROUP of records? Then the SCALAR MAX value is then processed by the CASE WHEN ... THEN ... END. Actually, I do no see the need for the need for the SELECT statement as this appears to be a pure ASSIGNMENT to a CALCULATED FIELD called "ShippedStatus".     I did not write this SQL command from 14 years ago. I am trying to understand exactly what it does, too. It apperar stehre

Comment: @Plant Theldea Maybe the (fake) sub-query should be re-written as ...                               `CASE MAX(lc.Status) 
 WHEN 'Shipped' THEN 'LOADED'
 ELSE  'PICK UP'
 END) AS ShippedStatus,

Comment: that would certainly make more sense.